# BaseEventLoop.run_in_executor() throws "unexpected keyword argument 'callback'" starting in Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-asyncio, python-3.5

I am running a function, `provision_ec2_node()`, via the default `asyncio` event loop [thread executor](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.run_in_executor). The function takes a number of arguments which I pass to the executor via `functools.partial()`.

```
task = loop.run_in_executor(
    executor=None,
    callback=functools.partial(
        provision_ec2_node,
        modules=modules,
        host=instance.ip_address,
        identity_file=identity_file,
        cluster_info=cluster_info))
```

This code works fine on Python 3.4, and I've been using it like this for several months.

However, I recently upgraded to Python 3.5, and now the above code throws this error:

```
TypeError: run_in_executor() got an unexpected keyword argument 'callback'
```

Looking at the [Python 3.5 release notes concerning `asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#asyncio), I don't see anything which explains this change of behavior. Furthermore, the 3.5 docs [still say](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio-pass-keywords) that `functools.partial()` is the correct way to pass a function with keywords to an executor.

What gives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently the second parameter was [renamed](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/111610562141a46f1eaac64d497d79fe13290847#diff-08afa52ab2b1511bee8527814ad44d80L468) from `callback` to `func`, <s>but the change was not reflected in the docs</s> change is reflected in the docs as of 2015-10-01. That's why it fails.

Either update it to the new name (and lose Python <3.5 compatibility) or pass the parameters as positional ones:

```
task = loop.run_in_executor(None, functools.partial(...))
```

Comment: Nice catch. I'll try this in a bit and report back. I know `asyncio` was marked as provisional in 3.4, but it seems strange they would break backwards compatibility over a parameter name. Would you happen to know why this change was made? I'm assuming it wasn't a frivolous change.

Comment: They break backwards compatibility for `asyncio` almost every release AFAIK. It's experimental and API is not stable yet. About why it was changed... `asyncio` is developed in separate repo and just merged into main `cpython` repo. According to source commit it was "[to avoid confusion](https://github.com/python/asyncio/commit/2798fb43af22c966a0c7ba15258a073cf651a3c2)". Which makes sense, since it's a function to execute and not a callback.

Comment: I see. It also looks like the next release of Python 3.4 (3.4.4?) will include all these `asyncio` changes from 3.5, per the [3.5 release notes](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#asyncio). So when that happens, you could theoretically be compatible with both 3.5+ and 3.4.4+.

Comment: Thanks for [reporting the docs issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue25284) to the Python issue tracker.